eslint indent - wrong spacing marked on multiline ternary expression
I have the following code snippet, where eslint indent lints my multiline ternary expression:

This is the error I am getting:
Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 16. eslint(indent)
So eslint expects 2 spaces per indent, even though I specified that there should be 4. I had the same issue with Switch Case before, but that problem was easily solved by editing the .eslintrc.json. This time, I could not find a fix like that.
My .eslintrc.json:
{
  "env": { "browser": true, "node": true },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": { "ecmaVersion": 2020 },
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended", "plugin:prettier/recommended"],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/member-ordering": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": ["error", { "functions": false }],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": "off",
    "indent": ["error", 4, {"SwitchCase": 1}],
    "prettier/prettier": ["error", { "endOfLine": "auto" }]
  }
}

I would like to know how to fix this linting error.

I figured it out:
"indent": ["error", 4, {"SwitchCase": 1, "offsetTernaryExpressions": 1}]

... specifically the "offsetTernaryExpressions" part fixes the problem. However, remember to restart the eslint server afterwards! I didn't do that before, and thus the rules never updated and the error persisted.
This is done in vsCode by opening the command pallete via Ctrl + Shift + P, then choosing ESLint: Restart ESLint Server
